# How to customize hot keys in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, ide, customization, hotkeys

Is it really possible to create your own hot keys in Eclipse?

For example, I want to create a hot key for creating folder.

Comment: using eclipse hot key,you want to create a folder in a project?

Comment: yes, I want to create directory in resource folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think this may help you little bit. 
go to `Windows`>`Preferences`>Select `General`>`Editor`>`Keys` page. Here the settings will be to configure your own hot key using plug-in `org.eclipse.ui.commands`.First, you need to define your new configuration

```
      <keyConfiguration
          name="My Configuration"
          parent="org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration"
          description="This is a simple configuration"
          id="org.eclipse.faq.sampleConfiguration">
       </keyConfiguration>
```

the below tutorial may help you clearly..
http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseCommandsKeybindings/article.html

Answer (score 2):

Why you didn't google it?

```
Windows -> Preferences -> General -> Keys.
```

In here, there is an option to set hot key to create folder. Just go there and set the keys that you want to use.

Comment: I know it. there are I can see hot keys but I cannot understand hoe can I modify